# What's the correct way to send RF with ESP32 and RF Sender module?

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I've used a RF receiver to scan my house remote control for alarm, and send the same frequency later using the RF sender module.

This is for ask Alexa to turn on/off the alarm (of course with a special code / phrase).

The receiver works fine and gave me this information:

```
Decimal: 128475011 (28Bit) Binary: 1110101010110101011101010101 Tri-State: not applicable PulseLength: 394 microseconds Protocol: 6
```

Then I programmed the send like this:

```cpp
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  mySwitch.enableTransmit(22);
  mySwitch.setProtocol(6);
  mySwitch.setPulseLength(394);
}


void loop() {
  mySwitch.send(128475011, 24);
  Serial.println("Sending 128475011 to activate alarm");

  delay(1000);
}
```

I also tried sending binary directly, but nothing happens...

What could be the problem?

Comment: 1110101010110101011101010101 in binary is 246110037, not 128475011. Also the receive you showed had 28 bits and you're telling having transmit send 24 bits.

Comment: Yes for security reasons I modified the values...

Comment: `128475011` in decimal is `0x7A85F83` in hexadecimal, it is longer than 24 bits. It is 28-bit with 4-bit alignment or 27-bit without padding 0.